# React + Redux State implementation - 2 associations to same collection, but 1 is a subset of the other

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

To learn more about structuring non-trivial react and redux systems I'm implementing a toy ticketing system.

The issue is I'm not sure on the most idiomatic way to structure the redux state.

**Background:**

All users are authenticated.

A subset of users may be linked to a ticket as the assignee, and any user can subscribe to the ticket to receive updates.

On the backend, an ActiveRecord definition would look something like this:

`class Tickets < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assignee, class_name: User
  has_many :subscribers, class_name: User
end`

The ui for a ticket should show a select list of possible users for the assignee, and something akin to a multi-select for the subscribers.

**The problem:**

I'm not sure if:

- I should I be pulling all users for a company into a single redux state, and then just filtering the users prop before passing a list of users to the assignee dropdown
- Or if I should have assignable users and subscrible-able users fetched from the server independently and stored in different states (which are combined, and maptoprops, etc.)
- Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach to handling relational entities in Redux is to store them in a "normalized" structure, and then use arrays of entity IDs to indicate ordering, filtering, etc.  For your case, you'd generally set up Tickets and User "tables" in your state, corresponding to your backend.

I've got pointers to some reading for you on this topic.  First, the Redux FAQ has a summary of [handling relational data in Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-nested-data).

Second, the Redux docs have a new [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section, which gives examples of a normalized Redux state, and resources for further reading.

Third, I highly recommend a library called [Redux-ORM](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm), which acts as an abstraction layer for managing that normalized data inside of your store.

Finally, I'm actually almost done writing a couple blog posts discussing concepts and techniques I've developed for using Redux-ORM in practice.  I'm hoping to publish those posts tonight on my blog ( http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com ).

**edit**

Update: I've published those posts on Redux-ORM as the first couple parts of [a series on "Practical Redux"](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/practical-redux-part-0-introduction/), discussing techniques I've developed from my own experience with Redux.

Comment: OK makes sense. Mostly... Using the example of tickets if a user was in the application all day, flicking between tickets would the state not just get ridiculously massive? Or am I missing some culling mechanism in redux?

Comment: Redux doesn't have any kind of "culling mechanism" - it's really just a pattern for organizing the "write" logic in your application.  If you want to clear out some of the data, that's up to you to implement.  That said, it's no different than any other client-side toolkit in that respect.